# Join tables with different column values

Tags: regex, join, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to join 2 tables, where the only possible join is by two different columns.
Column A is a twelve character long number, while the other (B) is a two character long number. They can ba joined, because A is like .BB......... , So the 2. and 3. char is taken from B (and in no other cases this is possible).

I think I should be able to use REGEXP_LIKE but how do I use a column in this function? '.column_name.........' isn't working naturaly. I tried to look around but I'm stuck now.

There are 20 some of rows in table B, and I would like to check all of them at once.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It would be good to see some sample data. As it is not clear what you are trying to do or ask.

Comment: There is table A with 8 columns abd table B with 3, I want to join them but the only way to do so is to make something like this: 903555555555 = 03 or 707123456789 = 07

Comment: So you want the 2nd and 3rd characters of the column of table 1 to be matched. Use `SUBSTR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we have a table *tblA* with a short number in column *colA* and a talbe *tblB* with a long number in *colB*.
We can create an intermediate table *tmpTblB* that includes all columns of *tblB* and a computed value *myNum* as a substring out of *colB*. Finally just join on *tblA* and *tmpTblB*

```
SELECT *
FROM tblA
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT tblB.*, SUBSTR( tblB.colB, 2, 2 ) AS myNum
    FROM tblB ) tmpTblB
  ON tblA.colA = tmpTblB.myNum
```